# Why did Moti Lieberman associate 子 with onset, and 了 with coda?

Tags: phonetics, orthography

Screenshot's from [YouTube](https://youtu.be/YON1pOcEhrA?t=363). I don't speak Chinese and don't understand the relevance of these ideograms. I emailed him twice, but after 5 months, got no reply.

[image]

Comment: Although there are theories that we can all spout, there is no _standard_ reason for association between these Chinese characters and initial/coda, and I think you've done all you can in contacting the content creator / editor.

Comment: AFAIK these characters aren't used in normal Chinese words for onset or coda. 子 is "child" and appears in one word for "consonant" (子音 *zǐyīn*); however, the traditional concept of syllable "initial", more or less the same as "onset",  glosses as "voice-mother" (声母)—the opposite idea of "child". As for 了, the core meaning is "end", but it's not used in the word for "coda" either (=音节尾 "syllable tail"). Neither are these particular characters used in Japanese equivalents.

Comment: The reason 子 is chosen to represent onset must be because it represents the Rat, the first sign of the Chinese zodiac.